# SSRS report viewer by default showing expanded data in Print Layout Option

Tags: reporting-services, printing, preview

There is an old report, which has some Collapsible column. Earlier on client side, report viewer was not showing some columns. This Discrepancy was happening only in Print Layout mode, Normal mode was working fine. At developer side there were no discrepancies, every thing was running fine.
I also want to mention that,clientn were recently migrated from sql server 2008 to Sql server 2019.
To Solve the issue I Open the report in Sql Server Business Intelligence Studio 18 & saved it. This Solved the old issue but now new issue has immerged.

Now in Print Layout Mode all the collapsible columns are always being displayed, irrespective of whether they are expanded or collapsed in normal mode.

To show the matter more clearly I want to post two Images.

[Collapsed Columns in Normal Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBOdJ.png)
[Expanded Columns in Print Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rvNH.png)